# How can I better handle this situation in ASP.NET MVC concerning my Partial Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a single view which has a menu on the left hand side and a container on the right hand side that is rendered from one of several partial views.

Right now I'm running into a situation like the following "Index" view:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="leftHandMenu">  
        // various dynamic menu items  
    </div>  
    <div class="rightHandPane">  
        <% if (Model.CurrentPane == "Sent") { %>  
            <% Html.RenderPartialView("SentPartial", Model.SomeData);  %>  
        <% } else if (Model.CurrentPane == "Inbox") { %>   
            <% Html.RenderPartialView("InboxPartial", Model.SomeData);  %>  
        <% } else if (Model.CurrentPane == "Alerts") { %>  
            <% Html.RenderPartialView("AlertsPartial", Model.SomeData);  %>  
        <% } %>  
    </div>  
       // various other common view items  
</div>
```

with the following actions:

```
public ActionResult Inbox(int? page)  
{  
    MessageListViewModel viewData = new MessageListViewModel();
    viewData.SomeData = messageService.getInboxMessages(page.HasValue ? page.Value : 0);
    viewData.CurrentPane = "Inbox";
    return View("Index", viewData);
}  

public ActionResult Alerts(int? page)  
{  
   MessageListViewModel viewData = new MessageListViewModel();
    viewData.SomeData = messageService.getAlertMessages(page.HasValue ? page.Value : 0);
    viewData.CurrentPane = "Alerts";
    return View("Index", viewData);
} 

public ActionResult Sent(int? page)  
{  
    MessageListViewModel viewData = new MessageListViewModel();
    viewData.SomeData = messageService.getSentMessages(page.HasValue ? page.Value : 0);
    viewData.CurrentPane = "Sent";
    return View("Index", viewData);
}
```

I realize this situation isn't ideal, but I need those portions to remain partial views.  I'm doing a bunch of ajax calls on this view to reload that "rightHandPane" with the various partial views.

I have a single view "Index", and then these various partial views which load a particular pane of "Index".  I'm passing in the view name into the ViewModel, and then have these if-else statements loading in the appropriate partial view.

How else could I be doing this?  I'm about to add 3 more partial views and this is starting to be a pain.  I'd prefer if I didn't have to maintain my currentPane in my ViewModel at all really.

Is there something I can do to avoid this situation all-together?  I've considered  using a Master View for the common portions but I need it to be a strongly typed Master View, which isn't that easy in ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use separate views for each actions with a master page taking care of all the common bits?

You can have a master page with a place holder for each section.

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="leftHandMenu">  
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftHandMenuContainer" runat="server" />
    </div>  
    <div class="rightHandPane">  
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="RightHandPaneContainer" runat="server" />
    </div>  
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterContainer" runat="server" />  
</div>
```

Then put view specific contents in each content page.

Comment: Well, some of the common bits are dynamic.  I'd need a strongly typed master view.  I can't do that without creating some Base controller, right?

Comment: The master page can have several different content placeholders where you could put your area specific content. ....I'll add to my answer.

Comment: The pattern is known as view composition and is the correct way of solving this problem. Factor out the common stuff into a layout and compose the view from the necessary partials using the layout to define the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write:

```
Html.RenderPartialView(string.Format("{0}Partial", Model.CurrentPane), Model.SomeData);  %>
```

but I would recommend you pass the name of the entire Partial View. My $.02.

Answer (score 0):

You could either

a) (if you're using, or will be using, ASP.NET 4) add a call to `Html.Action()` or `Html.RenderAction()` instead, and let the controller action decide which partial to render.

b) factor out the if-statements to a separate partial, or to a helper method. For example:

```
public static void RenderRightHandPane(this HtmlHelper helper, YourViewModelType model)
{
    switch(model.CurrentPane.ToLower())
    {
        case "sent":
            helper.RenderPartialView("SentPartial", model.SomeData);
        case "inbox":
            helper.RenderPartialView("InboxPartial", model.SomeData);
        case "alerts": 
            helper.RenderPartialView("AlertsPartial", Model.SomeData);
        case default:
            // Add a default handler - perhaps rendering a not found-view...?
    }
}
```

that is called like so:

```
<% Html.RenderRightHandPane(Model); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could "code by convention" and follow this pattern:

```
<div class="rightHandPane">  
    <% Html.RenderPartialView(Model.CurrentPane + "Partial", Model.SomeData);  %>  
</div>
```